Why is S5 modal logic universal?
S5 is equivalent to M+4+B. M restricts frame to being reflexive, 4 restricts frame to being transitive and B restricts frames to be symmetric. However, I don't see why this restricts frames to universal. Consider:
{aRa, aRb, bRa, bRb, cRc}
is reflexive, transitive, and symmetric, but not universal.

I think that by "universal frame," you mean a frame equipped with the relation in which each world is accessible from each other world.
The frames which interpret S5 modal propositional logic are the frames whose accessibility relation is, as you wrote, reflexive, transitive, and symmetric, i.e., the accessibility relation is an equivalence relation. Not every such frame is universal. However, any such frame is canonically a disjoint union of equivalence classes, each of which is a universal frame.
Furthermore, given a frame X, if a sentence p in S5 modal propositional logic is false in some world w in some interpretation valued in X, then restrict the interpretation to the equivalence class of w in the frame X. The resulting interpretation is valued in a universal frame, i.e., the equivalence class of w in X, and that interpretation also makes p false in the world w. Hence any sentence which is false in some transitive reflexive symmetric frame is also false in a universal frame. The converse is easy to see. So as far as soundness is concerned, universal frames work just as well as transitive reflexive symmetric frames, for S5 modal propositional logic. A similar argument shows that S5 modal propositional logic is complete for universal frames, just as it is complete for transitive reflexive symmetric frames.

The logic S5 does not restrict frames to being universal. The logic S5 is determined both by the class of equivalence frames and also the class of universal frames.
A universe of worlds might be partitioned into disjoint parts that are inaccessible to each other but where the worlds within each part are fully accessible among themselves. In your example, you have the worlds {a, b} in one partition and {c} in another.
